# how do you change the language of enchanting tables in 1.11?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Version 1.11 how do you change the language of enchanting tables?

I don't have a bin file and I have already tried other ways.

Answer (score 1):

No. Enchanting tables use a random set of glyph-like characters to create an artificial air of "mystery" to the enchanting process. Ultimately, the enchanting method is almost entirely random.

When you place an item in the enchanting table, it will show one enchantment relevant to the item, followed by "...?"

> *Efficiency IV..?*

***You are guaranteed to get this enchantment at the very least.*** The chance to get *more* enchantments are entirely random, however.

Additionally, once an item is placed in the enchanting table, those enchantments are locked to that type of equipment. For example, if you place in a pickaxe, then remove it without enchanting it, place in a sword, then replace it with a pickaxe again, you will get the same enchantments you got originally, until you actually enchant a pickaxe. The quality of the pickaxe is irrelevant. This means, you can waste bad enchantments on a wooden pickaxe, and keep trying to get good enchantments on your diamond pickaxe.

Using this method, you can at least try to aim for a better set of enchantments.